# how to cython class function's parameter accept c++ struct

Tags: python, c++, struct, cython

c++ header file code:

```cpp
typedef int TSecurityFtdcErrorIDType;

typedef char TSecurityFtdcErrorMsgType[81];

struct CSecurityFtdcRspInfoField
{

    TSecurityFtdcErrorIDType    ErrorID;

    TSecurityFtdcErrorMsgType   ErrorMsg;
};
```

c++ class header :

```cpp
class CSecurityFtdcMdSpi
{
  public:
    virtual void OnRspError(CSecurityFtdcRspInfoField *pRspInfo, int nRequestID, bool bIsLast) {};  
}
```

my pxd define:

```
ctypedef int TSecurityFtdcErrorIDType

ctypedef char TSecurityFtdcErrorMsgType[81]

cdef struct CSecurityFtdcRspInfoField:

    TSecurityFtdcErrorIDType    ErrorID

    TSecurityFtdcErrorMsgType    ErrorMsg
```

cython class define pxd:

```
cdef cppclass CSecurityFtdcMdSpi:
    void OnRspError(CSecurityFtdcRspInfoField *pRspInfo,
                    int nRequestID,
                    bool bIsLast) except +
```

if I try to define class in  pyx files:

```
cdef class CSecurityMdSpi:
    cdef CSecurityFtdcMdSpi  *_this_md_spi 

    cpdef OnRspError(self, CSecurityFtdcRspUserLoginField *pRspInfo,
                 int nRequestID,
                 bool bIsLast) except +:
          self._this_md_spi.OnRspError(pRspInfo, nRequestID, bIsLast)
```

but when I try to compile the code , console output:

`Cannot convert 'CSecurityFtdcRspInfoField *' to Python object`

How could I convert the c++ struct in python , how to declare  the struct parameter in cython , use `cdef` function or else?

Comment: You make a Python class to wrap the pointer.

Comment: @Veedrac what do you mean? can you show me a example?

Comment: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class

Comment: It would also help if you actually showed the whole error.