# How to pass struct pointer to __cinit__ of Cython's cdef class

Tags: python, pointers, struct, constructor, cython

I am trying to implement cdef class with **cinit** which must consume cdef struct pointer.

C header

```
typedef struct foo *FOO;
```

PXD files:

```
extern ...:

    cdef struct foo
    ctypedef foo *FOO
```

PYX file:

```
cdef class ClassX(object):

    def __cinit__(self, FOO arg):
        ...
```

And Cython compiler says "Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'FOO'". What is wrong and how to pass struct pointer to **cinit**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the similar question: [how to cython class function's parameter accept c++ struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214453/how-to-cython-class-functions-parameter-accept-c-struct?rq=1). Short answer: it is not possible to pass C-struct to Python (def) function. I have to wrap a struct into Python object.

Comment: Also, there is a relatively old message from the Python mailing list regarding this issue, noting that this problem is hard to solve in Cython, so we still need to use workarounds like static constructors
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2012-June/002734.html

Comment: @Charlie thank you though it is not actual anymore. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways I managed to solve it for my case, which are very specific.

**Method 1** - Convert pointer to a uint64 number (kind of dirty)
You have to make sure the reference isn't deleted before a copy, but first convert your struct pointer into an unsigned 64bit number and then cast and possibly deref back into your object. Like so

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
ctypedef unsigned long long uint64_t

...

cdef class SomeClass(object):
    cdef FooStruct foo

    def __cinit__(self, uint64_t arg):
        self.foo = deref(<FooStruct*> arg)  # preferably copy over keeping pointer
```

Then to construct it

```
cdef FooStruct yourfoo = ...  # your struct
cdef SomeClass res
res = SomeClass(<uint64_t> &yourfoo)
```

It's not the most pretty solution, but it'll work for specific situations.

**Method 2** - Same PYX file assignment function (preferable)
This method I found to only work with object references in the same PYX file. So if you define your `cdef class` with a setter function that copies the data over, which is not exposed to python, then you can update the internal struct.

```
cdef class SomeClass(object):
    cdef FooStruct foo

    def __cinit__(self):
        ...

    cdef void _set(self, FooStruct &data):
        self.foo = data  # copy
```

Now to construct it's two lines

```
cdef FooStruct yourfoo = ...  # your struct
cdef SomeClass res
res = SomeClass()
res._set(yourfoo)
```

Comment: Nice solution. To initialize in one line you can add the following method to the class:

```python
cdef class SomeClass(object):
    cdef c(self, FooStruct *data):
        self.foo= data
        return self
```

Then initialize with:

```python
SomeClass().c(&yourfoo)
```